# How to pass props to radio buttons in React.js

Tags: reactjs

In React.js,
The name of the room assigned to each home appliance
is got from the backend and displayed
I am trying to check the room to which the home appliance belongs with a radio button.

What I want to achieve is
I want to check (reflect on) the radio button that matches the room name assigned to each home appliance.

**Issue/error message**

Nowhere is checked like a photograph below.
in DropDownForRoomChangeButton.js
Since I can confirm that the contents are properly contained with console.log(item.item.room_name)
I wonder why it wasn't checked.

[image]

**DiscoverCondoRoom.js**

```
const DiscoverCondoRoom = () => {
  const [devices, setDevices] = useState([]);

  const getDevices = async(data) => {
    await axios.get('xxx.com',
      {
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          'Authorization': `Bearer ${cookies.get('accesstoken')}`
        },
      })
      .then(result => {
        console.log(result.data)
        setDevices(result.data.attributes);  
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
      });
  }
  
  useEffect(() => {
    getDevices();
  },[]);


  const keys = [
    "camera",
    "climate",
    "cover",
    "light",
    "lock",
    "sensor",
    "switch",
  ];

  const entities = keys
    .map((key) => (devices[key] || []).map((e) => ({ ...e, key })))
    .flat();


  return (
    <>
      <div className="row mx-auto text-center">
                {entities.map((entity, i) => (
                <div className="">
                <DropDownForRoomChangeBotton item={entity} />
                </div>
      </div>

      }
    </>
  );
}

export default DiscoverCondoRoom;
```

**DropDownForRoomChangeButton.js**

```
import Dropdown from 'react-bootstrap/Dropdown';

const cookies = new Cookies();

const DropDownForRoomChangeButton = (item) => {

  const [devices, setDevices] = useState([]);

  const getDevices = async(data) => {
    await axios.get('xxx.com',
      {
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          'Authorization': `Bearer ${cookies.get('accesstoken')}`
        },
      })
      .then(result => {
        console.log(result.data)
        setDevices(result.data.attributes);  
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
      });
  }


  const keys = [
    "camera",
    "climate",
    "cover",
    "light",
    "lock",
    "sensor",
    "switch",
  ];

  const entities = keys
    .map((key) => (devices[key] || []).map((e) => ({ ...e, key })))
    .flat();

  const roomNames = [...new Set(entities.map((entity) => entity.room_name))];


  const [val, setVal] = useState();
  console.log(val)
  const HomeHandleChange = e => setVal(e.target.value);

  const CustomToggle = React.forwardRef(({ children, onClick }, ref) => (
    <a
    href=""
    ref={ref}
    onClick={(e) => {
      e.preventDefault();
      onClick(e);
    }}
  >
    {children}
    <button className="btn btn-primary button_table_rightside">Unassigned</button>
  </a>
  ));

useEffect(() => {
  getDevices();
  setVal(item.item.room_nam)
},[]);

console.log(roomNames)
console.log(item)
console.log(item.item.room_name)

  return (
    <>

                    
                    <Dropdown className="room_change_dropdown_top">

                    <Dropdown.Toggle as={CustomToggle} id="dropdown-custom-components" />

                      <Dropdown.Menu className="room_change_dropdown">
                        <Dropdown.Item className="room_change_dropdown_item">
                          {roomNames.map((room_names, i) => (
                            <div className="flex_radio">
                              <input
                                className="room_change_radio"
                                type="radio"
                                value={room_names}
                                onChange={HomeHandleChange}
                                checked={val === item.item.room_name}
                              />
                              <p className="drop_down_p">{room_names}</p>
                            </div>
                            ))}
                        </Dropdown.Item>
                      </Dropdown.Menu>
                    </Dropdown>




    </>
  );
}
export default DropDownForRoomChangeButton;
```

HTML code

[image]

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to achieve here. In `HomeHandleChange` you set the `val` state with `target.value` (I think you mean `target.checked` btw..), and then in the `useEffect` you set it with `item.item.room_name`. What type is `val` supposed to be?

Comment: string. val should be room name and I can see it in console. item.item.room_name means where that device belongs. so I set it and try to assign checked

Comment: For example, like photo, Minoston Smart Plug 40 should be checked Unassigned Devices(this is room name.) but nothing checked

Comment: Ok, see suggested answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your comment, I think you were going for something like this:

```
const homeHandleChange = e => setVal(e.target.name);

<input
   ...
   name={item.item.room_name}
   onChange={homeHandleChange}
   checked={val === item.item.room_name}
/>
```

This way you set the state with the actual name of the room, not `value`, which in this case is meaningless.

Also, you don't need the `useEffect` for setting the initial state.
`useState` accepts a parameter for a default value.
So you can simply do:

```
const [val, setVal] = useState(item.item.room_name);
```

And then you can remove that line from the `useEffect`.

---

**Note:** Regular function, (unlike components / etc..), should be named in camel-case, not Pascal-case.
So `HomeHandleChange`, should actually be `homeHandleChange` like in the example above.
Obviously you can do whatever you choose but it's a matter of basic convention that's worth following IMO.

Comment: big help! works! thank you